# R - non-numeric argument to binary operator on matrices in shiny

Tags: r, matrix, input, shiny

I'm very new to r (and programming in general) and we were asked to make a web app using r shiny, the plan was to make a matrix operations calculator from different input files,(first .cvs file contains matrix 1, 2nd .cvs file contains matrix 2) but an error keeps appearing

```
 Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3420
 Warning: Error in FUN: non-numeric argument to binary operator
 99: eval
 98: eval
 97: Ops.data.frame
 96: renderTable [C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/FirstWebApp/app (1).R#45]
 95: func
 82: origRenderFunc
 81: output$oput
  1: runApp
```

this is my UI

```
     ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Multiple file uploads"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     fileInput("file1",
               label="Upload CSVs here"),
     fileInput("file2", "upload file here"),
     selectInput("ops", "Select Operation",
                 choices = c("addition","subtraction","multiplication","division"))
     
  ),
  mainPanel(
     tableOutput("input_file"),
     tableOutput("input_file2"),
     tableOutput("oput")
```

and my `server` looks like this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$input_file <- renderTable({
  file_to_read =  input$file1
  if (is.null(file_to_read)) {
    return()
 }
  read.table(file_to_read$datapath, sep = ',', header = FALSE)
})

output$input_file2 <- renderTable({
  file_to_read =  input$file2
  if (is.null(file_to_read)) {
    return()
  }
  read.table(file_to_read$datapath, sep = ',', header = FALSE)
})
output$oput <- renderTable({
switch(input$ops,
       "addtion" = input$file1 + input$file2,
       "subtraction" = input$file1 - input$file2,
       "multiplication" = input$file1 * input$file2,
       "division" = input$file1 / input$file2)
})
}
```

how do I fix this and if this error is fixed will the program run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input$file1` and `input$file2` will contain the file name and path, but will not contain the data itself (it gets read in elsewhere with your `read.table`). So, the matrix operations won't work unless you provide them with the data.

I would recommend consider using `reactive` expressions to access your data from the csv files. While a number of tutorials will demonstrate exactly what you have (reading in the data directly in an `output` `renderTable`, this might be less flexible for using the data in other contexts.

Below, the reactive expression `data1` will read in the csv file stored in `input$file1`. Then, to access the data, you just need to refer to it as `data1()`. This includes both `output$table1` (just to show the data in a table), as well as `output$table3` to show the result from a matrix operation. Note that in the below example, I renamed the `tableOutput` for clarification to "table1", "table2", and "table3".

I hope this clarifies things - let me know of any questions.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Multiple file uploads"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", label = "Upload CSV 1"),
      fileInput("file2", label = "Upload CSV 2"),
      selectInput("ops", "Select Operation",
                  choices = c("addition", "subtraction", "multiplication", "division"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table1"),
      tableOutput("table2"),
      tableOutput("table3")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data1 <- reactive({
    file_to_read =  input$file1
    if (is.null(file_to_read)) {
      return()
    }
    read.table(file_to_read$datapath, sep = ',', header = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    data1()
  })
  
  data2 <- reactive({
    file_to_read =  input$file2
    if (is.null(file_to_read)) {
      return()
    }
    read.table(file_to_read$datapath, sep = ',', header = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    data2()
  })
  
  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    switch(input$ops,
           "addition" = data1() + data2(),
           "subtraction" = data1() - data2(),
           "multiplication" = data1() * data2(),
           "division" = data1() / data2())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```